# Dell 1521 laptop - bluetooth not working

Tags: dell, laptop, bluetooth

I bought this dell without the bluetooth care and just recently bought and installed the bluetooth card on my motherboard but im still getting "no adapters found" - im lost and stuck!

```
$ lsusb | grep Bluetooth    
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)

$ lsmod | grep bluetooth    
bluetooth             391136  11 bnep,btusb,rfcomm

$ rfkill list    
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ lspci    
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS690 Host Bridge
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (Internal gfx)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (PCI Express Port 1)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (PCI Express Port 3)
00:12.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 Non-Raid-5 SATA
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI0)
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI1)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI2)
00:13.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI3)
00:13.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI4)
00:13.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB Controller (EHCI)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 14)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 IDE
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 PCI to LPC Bridge
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS690M [Radeon Xpress 1200/1250/1270]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)
03:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 05)
03:01.1 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C822 SD/SDIO/MMC/MS/MSPro Host Adapter (rev 22)
03:01.2 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C592 Memory Stick Bus Host Adapter (rev 12)
03:01.3 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd xD-Picture Card Controller (rev 12)
0b:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)

$ lsusb    
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05a9:2640 OmniVision Technologies, Inc. OV2640 Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 007: ID 0a5c:4503 Broadcom Corp. Mouse (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 005 Device 006: ID 0a5c:4502 Broadcom Corp. Keyboard (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c51b Logitech, Inc. V220 Cordless Optical Mouse for Notebooks
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub


$ dmesg | grep -e firmware -e hcd    
[    5.583089] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    5.596736] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-45-generic ehci_hcd
[    5.601132] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    5.660435] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-45-generic ohci_hcd
[    5.720366] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-45-generic ohci_hcd
[    5.780381] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-45-generic ohci_hcd
[    5.840363] usb usb5: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-45-generic ohci_hcd
[    5.900339] usb usb6: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-45-generic ohci_hcd
[    5.902118] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[   72.965813] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)



$ dmesg | grep -e bluetooth -e btusb    
[ 1800.542747] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb



$ dmesg | grep -e firmware -e hcd    
[    5.583089] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    5.596736] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-45-generic ehci_hcd
[    5.601132] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    5.660435] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-45-generic ohci_hcd
[    5.720366] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-45-generic ohci_hcd
[    5.780381] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-45-generic ohci_hcd
[    5.840363] usb usb5: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-45-generic ohci_hcd
[    5.900339] usb usb6: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-45-generic ohci_hcd
[    5.902118] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[   72.965813] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)

$ uname -a    
Linux dgnr8-laptop 3.13.0-45-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux



$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices | grep Vendor=0a5c -A8    
P:  Vendor=0a5c ProdID=4500 Rev= 1.00
S:  Manufacturer=Broadcom
S:  Product=BCM2045B2
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   1 Ivl=255ms

T:  Bus=05 Lev=02 Prnt=05 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  6 Spd=12   MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0a5c ProdID=4502 Rev= 1.00
S:  Manufacturer=Broadcom Corp
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   8 Ivl=10ms

T:  Bus=05 Lev=02 Prnt=05 Port=02 Cnt=02 Dev#=  7 Spd=12   MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0a5c ProdID=4503 Rev= 1.00
S:  Manufacturer=Broadcom Corp
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=10ms

T:  Bus=04 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=12   MxCh= 2
B:  Alloc=  0/900 us ( 0%), #Int=  0, #Iso=  0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
```

Comment: Can you add the results from `dmesg | grep -e bluetooth -e btusb`

Comment: $ dmesg | grep -e bluetooth -e btusb                             
[ 1800.542747] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb

Comment: `dmesg | grep -e firmware -e hcd` as I noticed a change in the kernel source and you probably have -45 installed `uname -a`

Comment: I have included into the main post - Thanks @Jeremy31

Comment: `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices | grep Vendor=0a5c -A8` hopefully this will indicate what device is bluetooth

Comment: DONE! Added to main post

Comment: Why is this being difficult `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices | grep btusb` or maybe you could search through the file devices.txt for info about what device is using btusb as a driver `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices > devices.txt` or you could paste the contents of devices.txt at paste.ubuntu.com and paste the URL here

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10129065/

Comment: did what was listed in the ANSWER - but still doesnt work....

Comment: You should consider filing a bug report of your own as that was the only thing I could find that even claimed to work

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/845531/no-bluetooth-adapters-found-on-ubuntu-16-04 This may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a local udev rule `gksudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/60-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules`

And enter the following

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10129429/plain/ copy from paste then save, exit gedit, reboot

It should work from the bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1315290

A found an incorrect attribute in the first paste compared to your device, use the same gksudo command and replace the entire file with the plain text version of http://paste.ubuntu.com/10146840/
Line 11 at the end needed to be `ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0", \` instead of `=="c0",\`

You could just change the c to an e, save, exit, reboot

Comment: I just got back around to messing with this again - changing line 11 FIXED me up!!! I really appreciate the help and time @Jeremy31

Comment: Great, I was starting to think that bluetooth device was a lost cause

Comment: Trying this (yes - 2019 - still the same Broadcom chip causing problems). I created this file and rebooted - still no action from the internal Broadcom bluetooth (though a bluetooth dongle works fine). I notice that hid2hci is mentioned in the file - should this be installed (I get command not found if typed at the command prompt)? An attempt to install it produced 'package not found'. (Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 64bit)