# Bluetooth adapter not found in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: bluetooth, broadcom

I recently installed ubuntu 19.10 and since then I have not been able use bluetooth on my laptop.

[image: bluetooth not found screenshot]

```
$ bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
```

I ran the following command.

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
```

which gives the following result. I can't understand this. Please help.

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1520 Half-size Mini PCIe Card [1028:000e]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
--
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1028:0413]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
ff:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c62] (rev 05)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04ca:00ac Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6417 Microdia Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:8162 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad [Synaptics]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 413c:8161 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.143018] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.288389] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[ 1984.492583] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[ 1984.492617] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 1984.492622] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 1984.492624] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 1984.492628] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 2078.137288] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 2078.137291] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 2078.137299] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

$ sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices | grep Vendor=0a5c -A8
P:  Vendor=0a5c ProdID=4500 Rev= 1.00
S:  Manufacturer=Broadcom
S:  Product=BCM2046B1
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr= 94mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   1 Ivl=255ms

T:  Bus=01 Lev=03 Prnt=03 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  5 Spd=12   MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dell 1521 laptop - bluetooth not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582916/dell-1521-laptop-bluetooth-not-working)

Comment: I don't understand what the script suggested does.

Comment: It runs `hid2hci --method=dell --devpath=%p` when finds a matching device.

Comment: I tried the script as a it was suggested, it did not work.